# Format Django Table Column into Currency and % format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I was wondering how I could format the numbers in a django data table into currency and % format?

> 12345 => $12,345
>
> 0.01 =>1%

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't have built-in filters for currency and percentage. You can write custom filters or use third-party packages. For displaying currencies there is a Django app:
https://github.com/panosl/django-currencies

Regarding the percentage there has been already a question at SO:
[Is there a django template filter to display percentages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751319/is-there-a-django-template-filter-to-display-percentages)