# Is there a Django template tag that will convert a percentage to a human readable format?

Tags: django, django-templates

For example:

- Convert 0.01 to 1%
- Convert 0.001 to 0.1%
- Convert 0.5 to 50%

I see in [humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/humanize/) there is nothing and I could not find anything in the Django documentation. I have tried `{{ value|multiply:100 }}%` without success. I know I can write my own template tag but I prefer to avoid doing that whenever possible.

> **UPDATE: I have also looked into the `widthratio` tag. For a value of 0.001 it goes to 0%. This is not what I want, unfortunately.**

Comment: you could use `{% widthratio value 1 100 %} %` but it's not very readable in my opinion since it wasn't intended to be used for that, so I'd make my own template filter which would also check for valid value (< 1).

Comment: thanks @dirkgroten. Please see update to question.

Comment: So the simple answer is: Make your own filter, it's a one-liner in your case.

Comment: Sure. But the 'one-liner' needs to be written and imported in every template that it is used. I was hoping for a solution such as 'humanize' integration, ideally in standard lib. Seems like a common enough problem to not use `widthratio.`Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have one file with a multitude of useful custom filters that I import everywhere. If I need to add a new filter or tag I add it there.

Comment: Have you found a human-readable percentage template filter or tag that automatically calculates the number of significant digits ? or did you write your oen custom filter yet ? I was writing mine based on bisect, but I found out it was not possible to use a sorting key in 3.7 ... I then decided to look for something already available. I'd appreciate you sharing your solution

Comment: Not yet. Haven't revisited this. I think I made a custom filter somewhere. I'd need to dig it up...

Answer (score 4):

I went ahead and created a template tag filter like this:

```
@register.filter
def to_percent(obj, sigdigits):
    if obj:
        return "{0:.{sigdigits}%}".format(obj, sigdigits=sigdigits)
    else: return obj
```

I was surprised to see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751319/is-there-a-django-template-filter-to-display-percentages) shared in another answer didn't have a clean solution like that yet. The best one I saw used a `try` block instead of the `if obj`... I personally want to see an error in my use case, but that's up to you.

Still, good to know there isn't a more "Django" way to do it that I saw. You'd use this in your template like...

```
{{{{mymodel.some_percentage_field|to_percent:2}}
```

where `2` is the number of significant digits you want.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael mentioned above, I will suggest you to write your own template tag for that : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Django built-in template tag `withraatio`

```
{% widthratio this_value max_value max_width as width %}
```

If this_value is 175, max_value is 200, and max_width is 100, the image in the above example will be 88 pixels wide (because 175/200 = .875; .875 * 100 = 87.5 which is rounded up to 88).

You can also see the details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#widthratio)

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to format a number with percent, for example "65%" :

```
{{ number|stringformat:"d%%" }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use one of these solutions: [Is there a django template filter to display percentages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751319/is-there-a-django-template-filter-to-display-percentages)

Hope it helps. If not, write your own simple filter :)