# converting and multiply float to int in django templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am fetching some data from a stocks API and I get some values (stored in the DB as float) 
as follow:

```
YTD Change 0.379996
daily % change 0.00854
```

my view is as follow:

```
def get_stock(request):
    empty = True
    localStocks = Stock.objects.all()
    if len(localStocks) > 0 :
        empty = False

    return render (request,'get_stock.html',{'empty':empty, 'output':list(localStocks)})
```

and my template

```
<section class="section-typography container u-readable">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Ticker</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Last Time</th>
            <th>% Change</th>
            <th>52W High</th>
            <th>52W Low</th>
            <th>YTD Change</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            {% if not empty %}
              {% for list_item in output %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>  {{list_item.symbol  }}</td>
                    <td>  {{ list_item.companyName }}</td>
                    <td>  {{ list_item.latestPrice }}</td>
                    <td>  {{ list_item.latestTime }}</td>
                    <td>  {{ list_item.changePercent }}</td>
                    <td>  {{ list_item.week52High }}</td>
                    <td>  {{ list_item.week52Low}}</td>
                    <td>   {{  list_item.ytdChange }}</td>
                  </tr>
              {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>    
{% endblock %}
```

the % change for the stock YTD is not 0.379996 but 37.99% and this is what I would like to display. Similarly the daily change is not 0.00854 but 0.85% . How can I manipulate the date either on the view or template to basically multiply it and display only the first 2 decimals of the float?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a django template filter to display percentages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751319/is-there-a-django-template-filter-to-display-percentages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a custom template tag. In your app directory create a new module named `templatetags`. Inside this module there should be a blank `__init__.py` and a random named file like `percentage.py`.

Your `percentage.py` should contain:

```
#percentage.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(name="percentage")
def percentage(value):
    return str(round(value *100,2))+'%'
```

In any html file you want to use this tag, you should load this tag at the start of the file with `{% load percentage %}`. In order to pass the required value to the templatetag, you need to use it like: `{% percentage list_item.changePercent %}`

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to change the value in view as follow:
YTD_to_pass = ((YTD*10000)//1/100)
this will multiply the value by 100 and keep 2 digits after whole number
then simply add a % symbol in template.